# For Bootstrap3 To Open All 12 Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

For some reason, no matter what resolution I open my page, I cannot get it to open with all 12 columns of width showing. It stacks everything vertically and only 6 columns wide.

My users end up having to drag the window wider to see the form as intended.

I am using completely vanilla bootstrap 3 css. With only color modifications. So I do not have any code to display because I only have the bootstrap css CDN for reference.

I have been bashing my head against this for awhile now.

Comment: We can't help without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given the fixed width size for your form elements.First of all make sure width should be in **100%** for adjusting itself based upon the screen resloution.
  If its not your problem, then show up your code in this question to find your errors easily.